# Combine results from multiple xpaths in xmlint

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I'd like to return the results from multiple `--xpath` phrases. I have tried

```
xmllint --xpath '//ItemGroup/Content/@Include' --xpath '//ItemGroup/None/@Include' --xpath '//Compile/@Include' -
```

This returns only the last xpath

I have tried the same thing using `concat()` however that returns only one match from each xpath:

```
xmllint  --xpath "concat(concat(//ItemGroup/None/@Include,' ', //ItemGroup/Content/@Include), ' ', //ItemGroup/Compile/@Include)" -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should you the [*union* operator `|`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#node-sets) like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '//ItemGroup/Content/@Include | //ItemGroup/None/@Include | //Compile/@Include' input.xml
```

With a sample XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="First Item"> aaa </Content>
        <None Include="Third Item"> bbb </None>
        <Content Include="Second Item"> aaa </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
    <parent>
        <Compile Include="Compiling is great"> aaa </Compile>
        <sub2> bbb </sub2>
    </parent>
</class>
```

the output is:

```
Include="First Item" Include="Third Item" Include="Second Item" Include="Compiling is great"
```

This does work with XPath-1.0.